# Undefined property exception when trying to instantiate dependency from IOC container

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to deepen my knowlade in laravel architecture.

1. I have a search engine (elastic search for the sake of the example), but this search engine might change in the future. So im trying to write a container for this, so in case i'll change the engine in the future, i will have to change only the container. (I believe the termenology is factory design?)
2. I have created a provider `app/providers/DataFromSearchEngine.php` that looks like this:

   ```
   use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

   class DataFromSearchEngine extends ServiceProvider {
      public function boot()
      {
       //
      }

      public function register()
     {
       $this->app->singleton('SearchEngine', function($app) {
          return new elasticSearch; 
       });
     }

   }
   ```
3. Then i registered it in the providers array in `config/app.php` .

   ```
   'providers' => [
       // providers...

       'App\Providers\DataFromSearchEngine'
   ],
   ```
4. The next step is to call `SearchEngine` from my controller:

   ```
   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

   use App\Http\Requests;
   use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
   use Illuminate\Http\Request;

   class SearchController extends Controller {

      protected $searchEngine;

      public function __construct() {
         $this->searchEngine = $this->app->make('SearchEngine');
      }

   }
   ```

But all these yields: Undefined property: `App\Http\Controllers\SearchController::$app`

Can someone explain what i'm missing?

Comment: Instead of using `$this->app` try using `app()` as non of the inherited controller classes have an app property on them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using `$this->app` try using `app()`.

This is because non of the inherited controller classes, i.e. `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` or `Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Controller` have an app property on them.

As a note you can use `app('SearchEngine')` which is the equivalent of `app()->make('SearchEngine')` as a shortcut to making your object.

Comment: Note that you can use `app()->make('Foo')` or `app('Foo')` as a shortcut :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when trying to create a service provider. I registered my service provider in AppServiceProvider.php but was still getting this same error. The issue was that in my ServiceProvider I needed to add `extends ServiceProvider` to my class. Seems simple but is often forgotten.